# Problem in adjusting contour label color and numbr of samples in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a contour plot using TikZ. I have two questions:

1. How can I change the contour labels color to all black?
2. Is it normal that gnuplot responds slow for creating smoother contour lines? what is the best way of creating a smooth contour line?

The code that I used is as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = {$\omega_\phi\left(x, \sigma\right) = \frac{\Gamma}{\pi{R_c}^2}\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(\sigma-R_0\right)^2}{{R_c}^2}\right]$},
        xmin=1.5, xmax=3.5,
        ymin=1.5, ymax=3.5,
        view={0}{90},
    ]
    \addplot3[
        contour gnuplot = {contour label style={draw=black},},
        samples=10,
        contour/draw color={black},
        ]
    {1/3.1415/0.25^2*exp(-((x-2.5)^2+(y-2.5)^2)/0.25^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When I want to create a smoother plot by using for example 200 samples, It takes a long time to respond. Is this normal? Because I have a super powerful computer. Even with 200 sample points, it does not produce the smooth contour line that I want. I am thinking of using 1000 sample points which takes forever. Everytime I want to compile my paper, I have to wait for a long time for a figure to see the whole PDF of my paper. Is there a better and faster way of creating a smooth contour lines?

Also, the label colors are mapped. I tried to force it to black but it used mapped color. The following is result of the above code using 10 samples.

[image]

Could someone help me?

Comment: 1. `contour gnuplot = {contour label style={nodes={text=black}}},`

Comment: With the fix of my previous comment, the `samples` settings do affect the output. Regarding compilation time check section 32 “Externalization Library” of the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) and [tag:tikz-external] on TeX.SX. The `standalone` class/package my help here, too.

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel. I used `standalone` package with no problem. Is there anyway that the package automatically detect the size of the `tikspicture` instead of manually set the document geometry using `\usepackage[width=3.00in, height=4.00in]{geometry}`?

Comment: I must admit, I have never used TikZ and `standalone` together, I only have seen it being suggested on TeX.SX. Have you taken a look into the [`standalone` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf)? You might also browse question tagged with [`tikz-pgf` and `standalone`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standalone+tikz-pgf). The `\tikzexternalize` approach would be much better because its built in TikZ. Finally, you can always ask another question

Comment: You can also try to _not_ use `--shell-escape`, so that gnuplot will not be executed and the values are read directly from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to  increasing the speed is to use a proper domain size. Using `domain` key as an option to `\addplot3` improves the speed while generating smooth contour lines. Here `samples=100` and `domain=2:3`.

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis on top,
        title = {$\omega_\phi\left(x, \sigma\right) = \frac{\Gamma}{\pi{R_c}^2}\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(\sigma-R_0\right)^2}{{R_c}^2}\right]$},
        xmin=2, xmax=3,
        ymin=2, ymax=3,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$\sigma$},
    ]
    \addplot3[%
        domain=2:3,
        contour gnuplot = 
        {%
            contour label style=
            {%
                nodes={text=black},
                /pgf/number format/fixed,
                /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
                /pgf/number format/precision=1,
            },      
        },
        samples=100,
        contour/draw color={black},
        contour/label distance=100pt,
        contour/labels over line,
        ]
        {1/3.1415927/0.25^2*exp(-((x-2.5)^2+(y-2.5)^2)/0.25^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It results to the following picture.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The initial value for the `/pgfplots/contour/every contour label` key—to which you append with the `contour label style` key—is <sup><sub>([`pgfplots` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots), p. 117,and `pgfplotsplothandler.code.tex`, ll. 1877ff.)</sub></sup>:

```
\pgfplotsset{
  contour/every contour label/.style={
    sloped,
    transform shape,
    inner sep=2pt,
    every node/.style={mapped color!50!black,fill=white},
    /pgf/number format/relative={\pgfplotspointmetarangeexponent},
  }
}
```

Interesting enough, the initial color (`mapped color!50!black`) as well as the fill color (to overdraw the plot itself) is set inside the `every node` style. Why is that so?

Taking a look into `pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex`, lines 2071ff., we can see that the `every contour label` is in fact applied to a `scope` and not a node. Sneaky!

We can also add stuff to the `every node` style with either `every node/.append style` or its short-cut `nodes`. But use `text=black` because solely `black` will also activate a black fill color, and `draw=black` will only draw the shape’s border.

Now the `samples` option does actually take effect.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = {$\omega_\phi\left(x, \sigma\right) = \frac{\Gamma}{\pi{R_c}^2}\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(\sigma-R_0\right)^2}{{R_c}^2}\right]$},
        xmin=1.5, xmax=3.5,
        ymin=1.5, ymax=3.5,
        view={0}{90},
    ]
    \addplot3[
        contour gnuplot={contour label style={every node/.append style={text=black}}},
        samples=100,
        contour/draw color={black},
        ]
    {1/3.1415/0.25^2*exp(-((x-2.5)^2+(y-2.5)^2)/0.25^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]