# Problem in modifying contour label style in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to modify the contour label style in a TikZ picture. I would like to have the label values in the format 0.0 instead of being integers. The following code produces a picture in which labels are shown as integers with no decimal point.

```
\documentclass[crop=true, border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top,
        title = {$\omega_\phi\left(x, \sigma\right) = \frac{\Gamma}{\pi{R_c}^2}\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(\sigma-R_0\right)^2}{{R_c}^2}\right]$},
        xmin=2, xmax=3,
        ymin=2, ymax=3,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$\sigma$},
        ]
        \addplot3[
            contour gnuplot = {contour label style={nodes={text=black}}},
            samples=10,
            contour/draw color={black},
            ]
            {1/3.1415927/0.25^2*exp(-((x-2.5)^2+(y-2.5)^2)/0.25^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The following picture is the result of the above code with 2000 samples.

[image]

How can I use the following code to adjust the label value format? For some reasons LaTeX complains about unknown key.

```
contour label style={
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the example in the `pgfplots` manual on page 118? Does this not work? `contour gnuplot = {contour label style={nodes={text=black},/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=1,}},` should to the trick.

Comment: It works for the example in the manual. I used the following code `contour gnuplot = {contour label style={
    nodes={text=black},
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,}},` but still the numbers are in integer. I also increased the precision but no change.

Comment: Ah, `samples=10` will create a plot where the numbers are smaller than 1 so they are actually 0.1, 0.2 and so on. If you want to have decimals even though the value is an integer, you can use `/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill` (boolean key, accepts values `true` (default) and `false`).

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used: `contour gnuplot = {contour label style={
    nodes={text=black},
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,}},`

Comment: Could you check [your previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100626/16595). Even your output shows the contour label as 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 and 0.4. If a higher value is used for `samples` the graph plotted is a) different (see also this question’s picture) and b) the numbers are integer. I’m confused. Let me post an answer (which I can delete if it does not work for your setup) and please check your PG/TikZ version by issuing `\pgfversion` in the document. The current version is 2.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass[crop=true, border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis on top,
        title = {$\omega_\phi\left(x, \sigma\right) = \frac{\Gamma}{\pi{R_c}^2}\exp\left[-\frac{\left(x-x_0\right)^2+\left(\sigma-R_0\right)^2}{{R_c}^2}\right]$},
        xmin=2, xmax=3,
        ymin=2, ymax=3,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$\sigma$},
        ]
        \addplot3[
          contour gnuplot={
            contour label style={
              nodes={text=black},
              /pgf/number format/fixed,
              /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
              /pgf/number format/precision=1,
            }
          },
          samples=50,
          contour/draw color={black},
        ]
        {1/3.1415927/0.25^2*exp(-((x-2.5)^2+(y-2.5)^2)/0.25^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]