# How to ensure equal font sizes in all included TikZ/pgfplots figures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to have many `tikzpicture`s in my document. Since each `tikzpicture` has its own size, I don't know how to manage the font size among all the pictures. Some of `tikzpicture`s are of size `\textwidth`, some are `0.5\textwidth`, and some are `0.4\textwidth`. Could someone help me find the best way to have all the font sizes of the ticks, labels, and texts of the picture the same size? When I look at the document, I don't see a consistency among the pictures. How can I standardize all the pictures? I would love to have other's opinions.

As an exmaple, suppose the following pictures.

[image]

As can be seen, there are different font size after scaling the `tikzpicture` to `0.5` and `1.0`. For `scale=0.5`, it is hard to read the picture. Having said this, suppose there are two completely different pictures in a document. How should I force the font size of these two pictures the same? In my document, one picture has the x-axis range from 1 to 10 and another one is 2 to 3. In order to accomodate the picture for example I have to use `0.5\textwidth`. I want to have for example the font size of the xtick and ytick to be the same for all the pictures in my document. I am looking for a way to achieve this goal.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Exactly how do you include your `tikzpicture`s? They are standard having the `TeX` font size, so I highly doubt that you have _inconsistent_ font sizes (unless you use the `external` library, or scale the pictures _including nodes scaling_???). Please provide a MWE which illustrates your problem.

Comment: You have to show us how you generated those figures, and do you use the `external` library? Note what has been posted in the answer, and in my previous comment, `TikZ` _does not_ on its own change the font size. So you must be doing something else than `\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}...\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}`, and we need to see what, in order to help you.

Comment: I put the `tikzpicture` in my document by using `\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \input{myTikZFile.tikz}
 \caption{}
 \label{fig:Asymm}
\end{figure}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the way you are creating such plots in your other posts, you can pass a `width` option to your `axis` command, which will scale the plot to the specified width without affecting the text.

[image: Sample output]

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[width=5cm,
        axis on top,
        xmin=-1, xmax=1,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$\sigma$},
        ]
        \addplot3[
                contour gnuplot = {contour label style={
                            nodes={text=black},
                            /pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1,}},
                contour/draw color={black},
                contour/label distance=1000pt,
        ]
        {exp(-(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=5cm,
        axis on top,
        xmin=0, xmax=4,
        ymin=0, ymax=3,
        view={0}{90},
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$\sigma$},
        ]
        \addplot3[
                contour gnuplot = {contour label style={
                            nodes={text=black},
                            /pgf/number format/fixed,
                            /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,
                            /pgf/number format/precision=1,}},
                contour/draw color={black},
                contour/label distance=1000pt,
        ]
        {exp(-(x^2+y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that pgfplots has some predefined styles like `tiny` or `small` which do not only choose a smaller width, they also change the fonts to `\small`, `\footnotesize` or whatever is suitable. These styles also reduce the distance of ticks etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're talking about. One of the strengths of TikZ is that, unless you use `transform canvas`, consistency is maintained in terms of font size across all `tikzpicture` environments in the document. As an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (.5,.5) node {hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    &
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (.5,.5) node {hello};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem clearly.

Comment: I make the PDF of each `tikzpicture` because some of them are time-consuming to be created (I use `gnuplot` for some of them). I then insert the PDF into my document and then use `\textwidth` to scale the picture to appropriate size. Please let me know if this explanation is not clear.

Comment: I don't use GNUplot myself, in part because I was raised on TikZ/PGF and in part because I've been told you quickly run into font-size issues with GNUplot. If you care about font-size consistency, I advise you to stick to TikZ/PGF as much as possible. And if some `tikzpicture` take too long to compile, you should build them on the side, in a different file, and add them at the last moment, when the rest of the document is ready. Alternatively, you can use the `draft` document-class option, which leaves pictures out of the document.

Comment: can you show me how to prevent from using `gnuplot` in this example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101408/23594.

Comment: You should not produce PDF of the `tikzpicture` and add them using `\includegraphics` with a different scale, or you're bound to run into scaling issues indeed. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Ahmad this means that you use the `external` library! When you do that, you ___must___ not include them and rescale the pictures, your saved pdf must be in the size you want them to be.

Comment: @Ahmad, however, you can use the key: `/pgf/images/external info` to save image size in and external file. Please see the documentation about this in the section __Bitmap Graphics export__ in the `pgf` manual.

Comment: @Jubobs, `\documentclass{jfm}` does not come with a `draft` option.

Comment: @Ahmad You provided no [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). I just assumed you were using one of the most common classes, such as `article`.